# How to prove law of mass conservation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, mass, rigid-body-dynamics

In our mechanics class, we began to discuss rigid movement. Let me begin with our definitions.

**Definition 1:** A map $f: D \subset \mathbb{E}^3 \to \mathbb{E}^3$ is rigid, if it preserves distance between points, i.e. for any two points $P_1, P_2 \in D$, we have $|P_1 - P_2| = |f(P_1) - f(P_2)|$.

**Definition 2:** Rigid movement is a one-parametric family of rigid maps $f_t$, $t \in I \subset \mathbb{R}$, which includes identity.

Then we said (very informally, since we don't know anything about measure theory really), that mass is some measure $dm$, which is absolutely continuous with regard to Lebesgue (volume) measure $dV$. By Radon-Nikodyn theorem, there exists a positive measure $\rho$, such that $dm = \rho dV$.

**Question:** We then stated that for rigid motion, the law of conservation of mass follows from the definition of mass. Precisely; for any part $U(t)$ of rigid body $B(t)$, the mass of $U(t)$ is constant. I've been thinking a lot about it, but have absolutely no idea how to deduce it. Is it something that follows from the definitions, but would require a lot of knowledge about measure theory and we just mentioned the result, or is it something that's so obvious that we just skipped the proof for that reason?

Perhaps we can just say that rigid transformations preserve volume, so $\frac{d}{dt} dV = 0$ and therefore $\frac{d}{dt} dm = \frac{d}{dt} \rho dV = 0$? Or is that not ok?

Comment: Who is claiming that one can prove the law of mass conservation? Like many physical laws, it's a broad experimental observation that's reasonably accurate under certain conditions. Of course, if one is already assuming constant volume and density, it's trivially easy to prove constant mass from $\rho\equiv m/V$.

Comment: I don't know if my answer is even correct, but it can give you some ideas.
since we know that law of conservation of energy is proved, and mass is a kind of energy(compressed energy), thus mass or amount of matter doesn't change anywhere, except if matter is converted to energy or vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Your edit statement is not valid, since you move the density $\rho$ inside the derivative, indicating you are assuming that the density is constant with respect to t and thus forcing the condition that mass is conserved.

As far as I am aware mass conservation is an assumption not a proof. You assume it is true and then formulate what that means in terms of a mathematical language.

Local Mass conservation can be expressed as a continuity equation, $$\iint \rho \vec{v} \cdot \vec{da} = -\frac{d}{dt}\iiint \rho  dV$$

This assumption fails when considering relativity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will then ask my professor ehat he meant by that statement. He did, however, only say that for rigid bodies and rigid movement.

Comment: For rigid movement you can also use this continuity equation, since dv would be a function of time and the mass would also be conserved